# Get object size in softlayer

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

how I can get object size from softlayer object storage using PHP client **without downloading** object to my server?

I had tried:

```
$objectStorage -> with('container/file')->get()->getHeader('Content-length');
```

but in this case object was downloaded to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using getInfo instead get example:

```
$size = $objectStorage -> with('mycontainer/myfile.txt') -> getInfo() -> getHeader("Content-length");
print_r($size);
```

Regards